# Positivity analysis of Transcendental equation

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to sketch the function  $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(5x^2+x)}{2-3x}$$

For the first derivative I get 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\ln(5 x^2 + x)}{2 - 3 x}\bigg) = \frac{10 x + 1}{(2 - 3 x) (5 x^2 + x)}+\frac{3\ln(5 x^2 + x)}{(2 - 3 x)^2}$$

Then I wanted to solve the inequality $ f'(x)>0 $  (where $f'(x)$ is the first derivative) to see if there is any max/min point, and then I would like to solve $ f''(x)>0 $ to see if the concavity is convex or concave.

The problem is I couldn't solve both $ f'(x)>0 $ and $ f''(x)>0 $ .

It's 3 days I'm looking for a way to solve it and I understood that it is a Transcendental Function and that there are some way to approximate a solution with e.g. Newton's Method (which is pretty cool), but it is a bit convoluted since i should also find the third derivative in order to solve the second derivative inequality.

My question is: Is there an easy way to find max, min and concavity of a function where its first and second derivative are Transcendental functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find a closed form expression for the point in $(0, 2/3)$ where the concavity changes, but you probably don't need to.  It should be enough to note  that $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0+$ and $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to 2/3-$, and $f'(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < 2/3$ (note that both numerators and both denominators
 are positive).

Comment: Hi Robert! Thanks to point it out! You are right! This is true for this function, but I'm trying to find a way to deal with this transcendental functions when I have them as first/second derivative.  The main point to me now, is that there is a Max point at about x=-1,95  y=0,36 and if i'm not able to solve f′(x)>0 how am I going to notice that there is a Max point there?

Comment: Again, you won't find it exactly, but you can notice that $f' > 0$ for $x$ sufficiently negative, while $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -1/5$, so there must be a local maximum somewhere between those.  Anything more is best done with technological aid.